# Make a link unclickable for a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that resends an email, but I don't want to let people be able to spamclick the link.

So I figured I need to make it unclickable for 5 minutes after it has been clicked.

I found out how to disable the click function like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){ return false})
```

or this:

```
$('a').removeAttr('href')
```

But how can I make sure if it is clicked the first time, people cannot click it again for 5 more minutes? And show an alert when it is clicked in the meantime?

Can this be done with jquery?

Comment: Best solution is serverside. So you remove the href, add an onclick. If they refresh, you would need to use a cookie to hold the state.

Comment: You can add timestamp on href itself, and keep state in browsers storage, or do it serverside, it really depends on your scenarion and what you are trying to prevent.

Comment: What's to stop someone just reloading the page? Javascript is only a part solution

Answer (score 3):

Rather than removing the `href` (which can cause annoying behaviour in some browsers) - you could leverage jquery's `.one` to attach a disabling event handler, and then remove it 5 minutes later.

Combined with pre-defining the original event handler, we can then revert back to behaviour before we initially clicked the link.

```
(function($) {
    var lockLink = function() {
        var link = $(this);

        link.on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            link.off();
            link.one('click', lockLink);
        }, 300000);
    };

    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('a').one('click', lockLink);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setTimeout` function:

```
$('a').on('click', function()
{
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $(this).removeAttr('href');

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(this).attr('href', href);
        alert('can now click me')
    }, 1000 * 60 * 5); // 1000 milliseconds * 60 = minutes * 5 = 5 minutes
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `data` method to store on the element the last time it was clicked.

```js
$('#clickme').on("click",function(e){
   let lastClicked = $(this).data("lastclicked");
   if(isNaN(lastClicked) || (new Date() - lastClicked) > (5*1000*60)){
      $(this).data("lastclicked", new Date());
       return true;
   }
   alert("You cant click for 5 minutes")
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="clickme">Click me</a>
```

You could add to this the use of `localStorage` to make it persist between page loads too, but unfortunately that is not demonstrable using stack snippets.

To do this you could pre-populate `data` from `localStorage` on page load

```
$('#clickme').data("lastclicked",localStorage.lastClicked);
```

and remember to write to it too:

```
 if(!lastClicked || (new Date() - lastClicked) > (5*1000*60)){
      var now = new Date();
      localStorage.lastClicked = now;
      $(this).data("lastclicked", now);
       return true;
   }
```

Final code:

```
let delay = 5*1000*60; // five minutes

$('#clickme')
    .data("lastclicked",localStorage.lastClicked || 0)
    .on("click",function(e){
       let lastClicked = $(this).data("lastclicked");
       if(isNaN(lastClicked) || (new Date() - lastClicked) > delay){
          var now = new Date();
          localStorage.lastClicked = now;
          $(this).data("lastclicked", now);
          return true;
       }
       alert("You cant click for 5 minutes (" + (delay - (new Date() - lastClicked)) + "ms remaining)")
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    });
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/7tpcyms6/

Comment: How can I use localStorage with this? I've tried it like this: `localStorage.lastClicked = tpj(this).data("lastclicked");` but when I try to log the content of localstorage, it says undefined. So If I put that in my if statement, the if statement is always false because it's undefined.

Comment: @twan updated answer. Just checking it on jsfiddle - will update with demo

Answer (score 0):

It's good to give the user some visible indication that the link is disabled.  Conveniently, your code can *also* use that indicator to determine whether the link should be disabled or not:

```js
$('#foo').click(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  
  if ($el.hasClass('disabled')) {
    // The link is disabled
    return false;
  } else {
    // The link is enabled; do whatever it is supposed to do here

    // ...then disable the link:
    $el.addClass('disabled');
    
    // ...and re-enable it in five seconds:
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $el.removeClass('disabled')
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  /* Adjust to taste */
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="foo" href="javascript:console.log('Clicked')">Click me</a>
```

This method avoids some UI issues that would arise from removing the href, and can cycle on and off as many times as necessary (a number of the other answers you've received here will only work once.)  It does *not* prevent the user from bypassing the timeout by opening multiple windows or reloading the page; if you truly need to enforce the delay you'll need to handle this serverside rather than in-browser.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to achieve your goal is to register  a function and remove it after the timeout:

```js
var disabledClick = function(){ 
    return false 
};

$('a').on( "click", disabledClick );

setTimeout(function(){
    $('a').off( "click", disabledClick );
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="www.google.com"> ask google</a>
```

Example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/xc1ra31a/

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="http://www.anylink.com" id="anyLink">Any Link</a>

<script>
$('#anyLink').on('click', function(){
    var href = $("#anyLink").attr('href'); //for further use
    $("#anyLink").removeAttr('href');
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getTime();
var after_time = time + 300000; //added 5 minutes to current time.
});
```

link is disabled now. make an ajax call here to save the state of link in DB or you can use localstorage as per your requirements.

And store current_time + 5 minutes in storage and check if current time is >= to the one which we stored earlier. and then make the link clickable again.

```
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getTime();
    if(time >= after_time) {
        $("#anyLink").attr('href', href); //clickable now   
    } 


</script>
```